# Phalcon's universal class loader can't find my class

Tags: php, class, phalcon

As a total php and phalcon newbie, I'm trying to use the recommended `universal class loader` using this code:

```
$loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();

// Register some directories
$loader->registerDirs(
    array(
        "php/assistants/"
    )
);

// register autoloader
$loader->register();

$test = new dbAssistant();
```

as I understand I have to reffer to the php file as a class what I have inside of `php/assistants/dbAssistant.php` is the following code, trying to connect to a database:

```
<?php

function connect() { 
    $connection = new Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql(array(
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => 'tt',
        'dbname' => 'testdb',
        'port' => '3306'
    ));
    echo 'Connected!!!';
}
```

again what I understand is that I have to refer to `dbAssistant.php` as a class and that's why I'm using `$test = new dbAssistant();`, but it gives me the following error:

`Fatal error: Class 'dbAssistant' not found in /var/www/html/test/test.php on line 18`

I know that it seeme normal, but the strange thing is that if I remove the `connect()` function and place the code out of it, I can see the `Connected!!!` echo, but it is followed by the same(above) error. I know that I'm missing something really small here, but as a complete php newbie, I really can't spot the problem.

Can you give me a push?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`php/assistants/dbAssistant.php` is not a class but a plain Php file. There should be a class in there with the name `dbAssistant`.

```
class dbConnect {

    public function connect() {
        ///Do your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this the correct way to connect to the db after getting a reference: `$test::connect();` ? :)